# Freeing memory allocated for a Tree - C

Tags: c, algorithm, memory-management, tree

I have a tree defined like,

```
struct tree {
    char label[MAX_LENGTH];
    char value[MAX_LENGTH];
    struct tree *child;
    struct tree *next;
};
```

Now I need to free the memory allocated by this tree. I wrote the following code.

```
unsigned int tree_free(struct tree *root)
{
    struct tree *current = NULL, *next = NULL, *child = NULL;
    unsigned int freecnt = 0;

    current = root;
    while(current != NULL)
    {
        next = current->next;
        child = current->child;      
        xfree(current);
        freecnt += tree_free(child) + 1;
        current = next;
    }
    return freecnt;
}
```

This method returns the number of items it freed so that I can verify it against the number of allocations made. This code works. But I am not sure this is the correct way of doing things.

This is a suffix tree implementation. For items s,stack,over, overflow, stackoverflow the tree will look like

```
root
-s
--stack
---stackoverflow
-over
--overflow
```

Any suggestions to improve the code are welcome.

Comment: You left out a few details: (1) what is the structure of the tree? from the code one can see it isn't the "vanilla" binary tree. (2) what is `xfree`?

Comment: It is not a binary tree. This is a suffix tree kind of implementation. xfree is just a wrapper around free(). A tree will have multiple child elements not just two like binary tree.

Comment: edited my post to make it clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to free a tree you need to walk it, so I think the code is correct. I would have done it the same way (recursively walk the tree, freeing the objects along the way). The only thing I would do differently is to run the xfree after the recursion (i.e. swap `xfree(current);` and `freecnt += tree_free(child) + 1;`). Because now you delete a node before you delete its child, but I feel that it would be better to delete the child before deleting the parent.

Also, you could get rid of the `child` variable as you use it only once, with a real need. Would save you `sizeof(pointer)` of stack space per recursion ;-)

Answer (score 1):

That's a fairly good solution. You're using recursion for the children (which won't go too deep) but iteration for the siblings (which *would* go deep if you used recursion). Your code could certainly be more elegant as a recursion-only solution (calling `tree_free` for both `child` and `next`) but the risk of stack overflow would be greatly increased so I think you made the right choice there.

Having said that, there's no need for `child` at all if you re-arrange the order of your operations:

```
unsigned int tree_free (struct tree *root) {
    struct tree *current = NULL, *next = NULL;
    unsigned int freecnt = 0;

    current = root;
    while(current != NULL)
    {
        freecnt += tree_free (current->child) + 1;
        next = current->next;
        xfree (current);
        current = next;
    }
    return freecnt;
}
```

If you think the length of your sibling list won't be that large, you could *try* the elegant solution:

```
unsigned int tree_free (struct tree *root) {
    unsigned int freecnt;

    if (root == NULL) return 0;
    freecnt = tree_free (root->child) + tree_free (root->next);
    xfree (root);
    return freecnt + 1;
}
```

It's untested so I make no statement of warranty or fitness for purpose, especially since it's probably dangerous for your specific case of a large number of sibling links. I include it more as an indication of what's possible with recursion. My advice is to use the first one.

Comment: thank you very much. happy to hear that the implementation was OK. thanks again.